# Custom fields of type string in youtrack

Tags: youtrack

Is it possible to create custom fields of type string and show them as the field description is shown? I would like to implement a bug database with YouTrack and it is impossible to do this if the field "steps to reproduce" must be written in a tiny column.

I am using YouTrack 2018.1.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible at the moment. 
Here's the feature request to get that implemented https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-6170